# How to put menu after other instead of over each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 3 menus in 3 different location on a website that they translate to one mobile toggle menu on phone.

My problem on mobile the 3 menus are showing up in the toggle panel but one over the other instead of one after the other. I define that this is a menu in my html using `.main-nav`

I tried appending .main-nav again but it doesn't work, I tried giving each menu a top margin in css it shows but along with its background.

**live example** - here how it is on codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VOeKpE

I want all 3 menus in the website to show the links one after the other instead of over each other now.

```js
if ($('.main-nav').length) {
  var $mobile_nav = $('.main-nav').clone().prop({
    class: 'mobile-nav d-lg-none'
  });
  
  $('body').append($mobile_nav);
  $('body').prepend('<button type="button" class="mobile-nav-toggle d-lg-none"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>');
  $('body').append('<div class="mobile-nav-overly"></div>');

  $(document).on('click', '.mobile-nav-toggle', function(e) {
    $('body').toggleClass('mobile-nav-active');
    $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('fa-times fa-bars');
    $('.mobile-nav-overly').toggle();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="main-nav float-right d-none d-lg-block">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html" target="_Blank">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html" target="_Blank">about</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**how it looks now**
[now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX5TH.png)

**desired result**
[result needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFOiB.png)

Comment: Set `display: inline-block` for `li`s.

Comment: Just FYI, cloning a menu in JS to amend it is a bad idea. I'd suggest using a single HTML structure and using Media Queries in CSS to amend it's layout for mobile devices.

Comment: thanks @RoryMcCrossan but this is a library im using.

Comment: What library? There's nothing referenced in the question. If you're referring to Bootstrap, then that's even more reason you should be doing this in CSS as it is out of the box behaviour

Comment: its a snippet not a library, i referenced it in my codepen link

Answer (score 0):

You could either use

```
li { display: inline-block }
```

Or

```
li { float: left;}
```

in your css.

the `<li>` element is by default styled with the `display: block` property. meaning it behaves similarly to an element like `<p> or <div>`, taking up the whole width of the content.

Changing this display property to `inline-block` ensures you still have the same functionalities you would also have with `display: block` but the elements will from now on only take up as much space as they need.

Comment: it doesn't work, i think the change needs to be on JS level

Comment: No, you need to change the CSS. Whether this is the correct property or not is debatable as the layout of the code in the question is very unclear, but you don't need any JS to fix this

Comment: ok @RoryMcCrossan so what should i change, what is not clear ? this is exactly how my code looks

Comment: We need to see an actual working example of the problem, ie. one that includes your CSS and shows the side-by-side cloning issue you describe.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so does the working example make it clearer ?

Comment: @mirvatk i looked at your code example but it seems to be working? Or can you maybe explain where exactly the error exists?

Comment: @TimGerhard the menu are overlapping in toggle panel on mobile instead of showing one after the other

Comment: @mirvatk I still don't get what you want. Maybe provide screenshots of the desired behaviour?

Comment: updated my question with photo of how it is now and how it should look like @TimGerhard

Comment: Well the error occurs because you use two <ul>'s and two <navs>. just use one <nav> and inside that one <ul> tag to keep things organized. that way everything will be below each other.